# How to get Inverse CDF (kernel) in R?

Tags: r

Is there any function in R which will calculate the inverse kernel(i am considering normal) CDF for a particular alpha(0,1).
I have found quantile but I am not sure how it works.

Thanks

Comment: Is `?qnorm` what you are chasing?

Comment: do you mean you want the quantile function for the normal distribution, `qnorm`?  @thelatemail: snap!

Comment: does qnorm works for kernel estimate? I dont know the exact distribution of my data. suppose i simulate 100 rv from N(0,1). II need to find F^-1(alpha) where F is the kernel CDF.

Comment: Seems as though I have seen an SO question just like this before. Done any searching?

Answer (score 9):

We can integrate to get the cdf and we can use a root finding algorithm to invert the cdf.  First we'll want to interpolate the output from `density`.

```
set.seed(10000)
x <- rnorm(1000, 10, 13)
pdf <- density(x)

# Interpolate the density
f <- approxfun(pdf$x, pdf$y, yleft=0, yright=0)
# Get the cdf by numeric integration
cdf <- function(x){
  integrate(f, -Inf, x)$value
}
# Use a root finding function to invert the cdf
invcdf <- function(q){
  uniroot(function(x){cdf(x) - q}, range(x))$root
}
```

which gives

```
med <- invcdf(.5)
cdf(med)
#[1] 0.5000007
```

This could definitely be improved upon.  One issue is that I don't guarantee that the cdf is always less than or equal to 1 (and if you check the cdf for values larger than max(x) you might get something like 1.00097.  But I'm too tired to fix that now.  This should give a decent start.

Comment: The CDF you have used here, is it kernel CDF? For very small value of alpha like 0.0001 it doesn't give the invcdf.

Comment: Yes this code would need to be modified for values of alpha between cdf(min(x)) and cdf(max(x))

Comment: I am new in R and its very complicated. thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please tell me why do we need to interpolate the density?

Comment: integrate expects a function as input.  The output of density isn't a function so we need to use approxfun to make a function out of it.

Comment: x can take any value between -inf to +inf, and cdf of N(0,1) should have value between 0 and 1, so does alpha. I guess alpha is q in your function. I couldn't figure out how to modify it.:(

Comment: @user2150536 I know that.  The trouble with my approach is that it assumes that the invcdf(alpha) we're asking for ends up giving a value between min(x) and max(x).  We could do a preliminary check inside of invcdf to see if that holds if we wanted to modify it to take any thing.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to use log-spline density estimation rather than kernel density estimation.  Look at the 'logspline' package.  With logspline density estimations you get CDF (`plogspline`) and inverse CDF (`qlogspline`) functions.