# Is there an equivalent to ksdensity(x,'icdf') in R?

Tags: r, matlab, probability-density

I've been using Matlab's `ksdensity` function to estimate the *inverse empirical cumulative distribution function* of some nonparametric distributions I have.

I've decided to give R a try, but I can't find any equivalent for `ksdensity(x,'icdf')`. http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html

Any idea? I would appreciate it a lot!

Juan S.

Comment: There are good search tools at CRAN.  Here are some possibilities:  `stats::density` , `stats::ksmooth`, the `KernSmooth` package.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWitthoft, I know about them, the problem is that whith these packages I can't estimate the _inverse empirical cumulative distribution function_, but only the density estimation.

Comment: Ok, then maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331307/how-to-get-inverse-cdf-kernel-in-r  ... threads in R-help mailing list archives suggest using `quantile`

Comment: Thanks again @CarlWitthoft, then I guess there is no such thing as an equivalent and I need to write my own code as suggested in the thread you sent me.